# Украинская локализация сайта на опенкарт

Tags: opencart, локализация

Всем добра! Нужно сделать украинскую локализацию сайта на ocstore Version 2.3.0.2.3. Погуглила, скачала локализации установила, но в итоге ничего адекватно не работает) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать с этими иероглифами?

Comment: какие шрифты используете?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin футер использует font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif

Comment: Сайт онлайн или на локалке?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin сайт на локалке (open server)

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать другие шрифты? Есть результаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в ошибках. Подключенный модуль корзины не подтянул сразу переменые, из-за этого все вывалилось. Отключила его, включила, и все заработало)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по скринам проблема не в локализации, а в подключаемых шрифтах. Тот, который Вы используете не поддерживает украинский.

Comment: font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;